# html - Links to anchors not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have made a website that has been working for me while I build it (Chrome) but when I got around to trying other browsers on other systems... IE won't let my `navbar` links to anchor points work. The site is a mess and a bit complex. Here is a rough outline of the body and content in the page:

```
<a1 class="anchor" id="home"></a1>
<div id="home">
[content]
</div>
<a1 class="anchor" id="fish_shop"></a1>
<div id="fish_shop">
[content]
</div>
<a1 class="anchor" id="fish_cafe"></a1>
<div id="fish_cafe">
[content]
</div>
```

and here is the `css` for the anchors that I have to offset due to a navbar and fixed slideshow at the top of the screen.

```
a1.anchor {
display: block; 
position: relative; 
top: -333px; 
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Also if this means anything, I have  at the top of the page, even though its a `.php` file.

[EDIT]
These are in my bootstrap navbar.

```
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" style="font-family: lanenarrowlight; font-weight:bolder;text-align: center" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" style="font-family: lanenarrowlight; font-weight:bolder;text-align: center" href="#fish_shop">FISH SHOP</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" style="font-family: lanenarrowlight; font-weight:bolder;text-align: center" href="#fish_cafe">FISH CAFE</a></li>
```

Comment: There is no a1 tag in HTML elements. Please check your code once.

Comment: Should the tag you want to link have a name attribute matching the #value of the link?

Comment: <a1> is customized tag for their custom use.? as i think

Comment: @weedrummerman please be more clear what your expected out put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
<a1 class="anchor" id="home"></a1>
<a1 class="anchor" id="fish_shop"></a1>
<a1 class="anchor" id="fish_cafe"></a1>
```

to:

```
<a class="anchor" href="home"></a1>
<a class="anchor" href="fish_shop"></a1>
<a class="anchor" href="fish_cafe"></a1>
```

and after that replace this line in your css:

```
a1.anchor {
```

to:

```
a.anchor {
```